# SerializerMethodField llamando de otro apps.catalogos.models

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Buen día espero puedan ayudarme, tengo un serializer de mi tabla apps.control.models, en el cual tengo una ForeignKey a una tabla en otra app, apps.catalogos.models, como esta serializado lo que me manda es el id de dicho registro, con SerializerMethodField hago lo siguiente para obtener de la misma tabla el nombre de un registro guardado en un Choice de esta manera

Models de tabla movimientos:

```
class Movimiento(models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, choices=TIPO)# Compra o Nacimiento
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, choices=DESCRIP)# Tipo de animal. Semental, Engorda, Vientre, Reemplazo, Producto
    fecha = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    arete = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    raza = models.ForeignKey(Raza, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='raza')
    peso = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    observaciones = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.arete
```

Choice:

```
TIPO = (('C', 'Compra'),
            ('N', 'Nacimiento'),
            )
```

Modelo Raza de otra apps

```
class Raza(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=4,blank=True,null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Mi Serializer de la primera apps

```
class MovimientoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    descripcion = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    tipo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Movimiento
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_descripcion(self,obj):
        dato = obj.get_descripcion_display()
        return dato

    def get_tipo(self,obj):
        dato = obj.get_tipo_display()
        return dato
```

Como le hago para q en mi pagina no me muestre el numero de la id raza, si no el nombre, en cuestion del Choice puedo hacerlo asi como lo muestro pero en ese campo no se como hacerlo??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias ya pude hacerlo

```
class MovimientoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
raza = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="nombre", queryset=Raza.objects.all())
```

Tomando los ejemplos de la siguiente liga da los ejemplos de la relaciones y como solo obtengo el id, realiza la consulta para traer el nombre de ese id. Gracias

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Otra forma Como ya tengo serializado mis modelos, lo mando a importar y lo presento:

```
class MovimientoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    descripcion = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    tipo = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)    
    raza = RazaSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Movimiento
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_descripcion(self,obj):
        dato = obj.get_descripcion_display()
        return dato

    def get_tipo(self,obj):
        dato = obj.get_tipo_display()
        return dato
```

De esta manera, como ya mando a llamar el serializer de raza, lo único que hice fue llamarlo y dentro de mi serialixer de movimiento lo tengo, así como ya lo tengo en este, cuando lo presento el json me trae esa serialización y lo unico que hago es indicarle que en raza es raza.nombre y así lo resolvi.

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 11,
        "descripcion": "Semental",
        "tipo": "Compra",
        "razaanimal": {
            "id": 3,
            "codigo": "BB",
            "nombre": "Blackbelly",
            "color": "#935116"
        },
        "razamadre": null,
        "razapadre": null,
        "fecha": "2019-05-08",
        "hato": "Es la primera prueba hecha",
        "arete": "A-001",
        "tatuaje": "001"
   }
]
```

También aproveche a utilizar viewset y router para que solo un json me sirva para el POST, GET, PUT y PATCH. Y así ahorrarme más código. Agradezco a la comunidad. y por su puesto mejore mis vistas, con el frontend estoy utilizando Vue.js 2. Acá el resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]